# VBA - Excel - Filling a cell with a nested IF

Tags: excel, vba, nested-if

I'm using VBA to hack and splice together a macro to update a quickbooks exported report.  I'm using a nested IF formula to create a filter for myself.

The formula I'm using is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I2),IF(ISBLANK(I3),IF(ISBLANK(H2),IF(ISBLANK(H3),"X",""),""),""),"")
```

(This will fill a cell with an X, if the 4 referenced cells are blank, and do nothing if any of them have a value).

The code I tried is this:

```
Range("N2").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(I2),IF(ISBLANK(I3),IF(ISBLANK(H2),IF(ISBLANK(H3),"X",""),""),""),"")"
```

The problem I'm having is that the `"` before the `X` is being read as the end of the code (I think); I'm getting a compile error.

Anyone able to help me out a little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using excel formula in VBA code, you have to careful with double quote:

Check the below code, it will work for you:

```
Range("N2").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(I2),IF(ISBLANK(I3),IF(ISBLANK(H2),IF(ISBLANK(H3),""X"",""""),""""),""""),"""")"
```